# Flutter build appbundle generate wrong environment variable for staging and production app

Tags: android, flutter

I am quite new in Flutter deployment and is struggling with some weird issue. Things were going fine until one day, when I issue the command `fvm flutter build appbundle`, it generate two .aab releases with favors - staging and production. I tried to upload staging .aab file to my staging project in Play Console. When I download the staging app from the Play Store, the app refers to production environment hence calling the wrong API. It turns out that no matter how I cleanup the project with `fvm flutter clean` and delete build folder manually, it always build staging app and production app with production variables. It works fine in emulator using staging configuration in Android Studio. I not sure what code snippet to provide, and I try to search for similar issue but not able to find one. I apologize if it is a bad question, I have been trying to build and upload for hours and it is still behave the same. iOS works fine though.

The code detect environment with this

```
  factory Constants.of() {
    if (_instance != null) {
      return _instance!;
    }

    final flavor = EnumToString.fromString(
      Flavor.values,
      const String.fromEnvironment('FLAVOR'),
    );

    switch (flavor) {
      case Flavor.staging:
        _instance = Constants._stg();
        break;
      case Flavor.production:
      default:
        _instance = Constants._prd();
    }
    return _instance!;
  }
```

In app/build.gradle

```
    flavorDimensions "environment"
    productFlavors {
        staging {
            dimension "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
            versionNameSuffix "-Stg"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.staging
        }

        production {
            dimension "environment"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.production
        }
    }
```

Not sure if it helps

Comment: Can you please share how are you identifying the environment? If you build an *.APK is the behavior the same?